# Single Spring mvc 4 controller with no @RequestMapping returns strips css from my html view

Tags: java, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have a simple controller in a spring boot mvc app packaged as a .war (for aws deployment). I have Thymeleaf on the build path and bootstrap 3.3.6 in resources/static folder. I use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in the main.

This controller displays a view just fine.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/handeware")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewHome() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

However, when I remove the `@RequestMapping` part like this

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewHome() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

It appears that the view gets returned with the Bootstrap CSS styling stripped.

Essentially, I have a domain name www.blah.com with the CNAME pointing to my spring mvc app hosted in aws elastic beanstalk. The idea is that I want someone to be able to type www.blah.com into the browser and be able to see my home page. In order to do this, I removed the @RequestMapping's from my controller, and it works. People can now visit my site at www.blah.com and see my home.html. However, the CSS styling is not showing up now. If I add the `@RequestMapping` back, the CSS shows back up. Isn't that odd? I confirmed in my local as well as in aws that this is the case. Not sure what to make of it.

Comment: There's one `@RequestMapping` left in the second sample, is that intentional? I think that in the second sample you are specifically mapping the `http://www.blah.com/` to a view called "home", which may cause it display differently than if it were being served by as a static resource (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you reference your css files from your html? You may need to update those references to match the new path.